# Powershell Change Organizational Units to Title Case

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I am trying to set the display name on my OUs to be title case. The boss says its hard to read.

```
foreach( $item in $ORGOU ) { Set-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $item.DistinguishedName -Replace -DisplayName (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($item.Name.ToLower()) }


Error:
Set-ADOrganizationalUnit : Missing an argument for parameter 'Replace'. Specify a parameter of type
'System.Collections.Hashtable' and try again.
At line:1 char:89
+ ... OrganizationalUnit -Identity $item.DistinguishedName -Replace -Displa ..
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Besides the bad syntax.

Comment: Can you change an OU name in powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Set-AD*` cmdlets offer you 2 syntaxes for doing this, you just need to choose *one*:

Either use the `-DisplayName` parameter:

```
Set-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $item.DistinguishedName -DisplayName (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($item.Name.ToLower())
```

Or use one of the `-Replace`/`-Add` parameters, in which case you need to provide a hashtable of attribute names and values to set (this is what the error is trying to suggest):

```
Set-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $item.DistinguishedName -Replace @{description=(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($item.Name.ToLower())}
```

Comment: This is really good but why can't I change the OU name?

Comment: @celticadmin I think you'll want [`Rename-ADObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/rename-adobject) for that

Comment: Thanks I just rebuilt the OUs structure since the OUs were empty with Title Case.